# Hazelcast Map reload on demand

Tags: hazelcast

**HazeCast 3.2-RC1 Evaluation:**

I am not able find any HazelCast api to re-load i.e, trigger `MapLoader (loadAllKeys(), loadAll()`) on-demand.

I see this autoload (ALL) happens only when Server starts,  But I need a control to re-load on demand when required to re-synchronize  with underlying database.

`Map.clear()` clears all the data, but not finding any control to  to re-load automatically rather write additional code to populate the data and push it to the cache?

Can some advise if there are any workarounds?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

the documentation says that the MapStore is called if a key is not in memory. So after you clear the Map will be populated by simply call get() on it. You will only have the data in memory that is really used.

On the other hand, MapStore is called "when the map is first touched/used". Maybe you can create a new hazelcast map and switch to the new map.

see http://www.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#persistence for more information.

Regards
Thorsten